# Why is Tal talking about 10. Qf7 when 10.... N5f6 is possible?

Tags: books, attack, annotation, tal

I am picking from the book "Attack with Mikhail Tal" Chapter 1, pg 6. Tal annotates the steps and his thought process on the Tal-Larsen 1965 match.

```
[FEN ""]

1. e4 Nf6 2. e5 Nd5 3. d4 d6 4. Nf3 dxe5 5. Nxe5 Nd7 6. Nxf7 Kxf7 7. Qh5+ Ke6 8. c4 N5f6
```

Tal continues with 9. d5+ Kd6 10 Qf7 Ne5. I am stuck on the Qf7. Why is Qf7 possible when there is 10... N5f6? What am I missing here?

Here is the original excerpt.

[image: Page 6- Attack with Mikhail Tal]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You made a mistake when transcribing move 7. It is **7. Qh5+**, not **7. Qf3+**. Move 10 is then **Qh5f7**, which is not blocked by the Nf6.

```
[FEN ""]

1. e4 Nf6 2. e5 Nd5 3. d4 d6 4. Nf3 dxe5 5. Nxe5 Nd7 6. Nxf7 Kxf7 7. Qh5+ Ke6 8. c4 N5f6 9. d5+ Kd6 10. Qf7 Ne5
```

Comment: This was embarassing. Sorry! I went over and over again, and I completely missed this.